# Magento 2.3.3 - Configurable Price Disappears

Tags: magento2.3.3, configurable-price

I've noticed that in Magento 2.3.3 that the Configurable Product price is gone (in grid view) when there are simple products added. Also, I cannot add this in - the price field allows me to enter a price but it never saves.

Is there a way to still keep the Configurable Product price even with Simple products?

The Configurable Product price is required for an api integration that uses that Configurable price field to determine the base RRP (and not the simple price).

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you cannot set a price for a configurable parent product.

Whilst the admin interface may let you enter a price when you create the configurable product this will be ignored/removed when the product is complete and all pricing for the product will then be calculated from the simple product variations added to the configurable product.